# Get all addresses for specific place/company

Tags: google-api, street-address

What I'm trying to do is collect all addresses for list of companies and trying to get it with Google Map Api.

For example when I search for "Burger King" at maps.google.com I recieve 600k+ results:

- 20 pages of detailed results I can use
- Way more "pointers" on map - but they come with images as part of map data - so can't parse it.

There is new Google Places API - I'm not sure if it fit my requirements - I need to specify coordiantes+radius there so I can't get data for whole US or World.

My question is - if there any way to get that kind of data with Google API or are there any other reliable sources?
Thanks!